# Identity Server 4 login existing database

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am new in identity server and I have an existing database which is not same as Asp.net identity tables, but I saw many examples and video tutorials which were using asp.net identity for login. The problem is I don't want to use asp.net identity. How do I use identity server as single sign on?

```
services.AddIdentityServer(option => {
    option.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Accounts/Login";
    })
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Constants.GetApis())
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Constants.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Constants.GetClients())
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential(persistKey: false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to get rid of asp.net identity.
Jut implement the IUserStore and as shown in below implementation your own mechanism to get the data from existing database.following are some examples to implement IUserStore

```
 public async Task<Users> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //here you have to write the code to get data from existing db like ado.net or some third party api
    }
```

In below method you have to create a poco class for your user table in existing db and pass it.

```
public Task<string> GetUserIdAsync(Users user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.user_id.ToString());//user_id will be replaced by your user id column name
    }
```

Also add your User poco class as shown

```
 var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
                              .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                              //.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
                              //.AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                              .AddClientStore<ClientStore>()
                              .AddResourceStore<ResourceStore>()
                              .AddAspNetIdentity<Users>()//here
```

Comment: i am using same thinks which you told but i am receiving this error identity server 4 sub claim is missing

Comment: This may help https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2292

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `IProfileService` in your own class, to fetch user data from your own data store. It can be any type of storage/schema. Documentation for `IProfileService` is [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html).

After you implement your class, you have to register it using extension method:

```cs
builder.AddProfileService<MyCustomUserProfileService>();
```

where `builder` is of type `IIdentityServerBuilder`.

In addition, using similar logic, you have to implement your own password validator logic, using `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` interface (documentation [here](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/resource_owner.html)) and register your implementation class using extension method:

```cs
builder.AddResourceOwnerValidator<MyCustomUserResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can implement our own Identity Storage.

- Data Storage
- UserService and ProfileService
- Inject the services into AccountControllers

## Data Storage

Implement your own **IdentityDbContext** with your own User related entity models.

```
public class IdentityDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserLogin> UserLogins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserSecret> UserSecrets { get; set; }

    public IdentityDbContext(
      DbContextOptions<IdentityDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        ...
    }
}
```

Make sure there is a **ConcurrencyStamp** to avoid the concurrency problem for load balance servers.

```
public class User : IConcurrencyAware
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string SecurityCode { get; set; }

    public DateTime SecurityCodeExpirationDate { get; set; }
           
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public ICollection<UserClaim> Claims { get; set; } = new List<UserClaim>();
    public ICollection<UserLogin> Logins { get; set; } = new List<UserLogin>();
    public ICollection<UserSecret> Secrets { get; set; } = new List<UserSecret>();
}
```

The implementation of Data Storage is very traditional Entity Framework.

## UserService and ProfileService

- ProfileService should implement `IdentityServer4.Services.IProfileService`
  [image]
  We will have `GetProfileDataAsync()` and `IsActiveAsync()` here.
- A UserService should handle all the CRUD operations and common functions like resetting password, check active user..., and can be extended to have external login features.

## Inject to Controllers

Hook UserService and ProfileService to the related controllers to handle UI requests (login, logout, ...)

[image]

[image]

I folllowed an excellent Kevin Dockx course ([Dealing with Credentials when Securing an ASP.NET Core 3 Application](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/dealing-credentials-when-securing-aspdotnet-core-3-application/table-of-contents)) on PluralSight.

The source code is in GitHub.
https://github.com/KevinDockx/DealingWithCredentialsWhenSecuringAspNetCore3

But the course is using IdentityServer4 version 3.x. For the latest, 4.0.x, we can get the user management code from the [QuickstartUI repository](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI).

Just switch the `TestUserStore` with our own user service.
[image]

IdentityServer4 is very powerful. Hope this answer can help you get started.